# Launching app in Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have an app that I want to only work with in Landscape.

For the first time ever, I'm foregoing IB and trying to set up all my views programmatically, so I'm creating a view and adding a bunch of subviews in loadView method:

```
self.view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];

// Create a GMSCameraPosition that tells the map to display the
// coordinate -33.86,151.20 at zoom level 6.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];

self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
self.mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.mapView.delegate = self;
self.mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeHybrid;
self.mapView.frame = self.view.frame;
[self.view addSubview:self.mapView];

// add the toolbar
UIToolbar* toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 44, self.view.frame.size.width, 44);
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
NSMutableArray* items = [NSMutableArray array];
[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"location-arrow.png"]
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                 target:self
                                                 action:@selector(locateMe:)]];
[items addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tools"
                                                  style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                                 target:self
                                                 action:@selector(toolsButtonTapped:)]];
[toolbar setItems:items];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

In my project settings, I have disabled both portrait orientations. I also have this in my root view controller:

```
// Enforce Landscape Orientation
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{ 
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

My problem is that the simulator *starts* in landscape mode, but all of the views are sized for portrait - so the bottom chunk of my views are below the screen and the right side of my screen is a big empty region.

I tried fixing this by switching the width and height of the application frame in the first line, but then that leaves some empty vertical room on the left edge of the screen for the status bar.

So, what's the correct way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Just wondering, what happens when testing on a device?

Comment: you can try `self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation( M_PI / 2 );`

Comment: @Squatch: This is a an app for a new client, so it's created with their account, which I can't join in as a member until the member centre comes back up, so I can't run it on the device.

Comment: @Virussmca: Is that a 90 degree turn? I don't get how that helps. I'll try it tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]`

try using `[[[[[self view] window] rootViewController] view] bounds]`

The bounds will represent the width and height correctly in Landscape orientation, because the bounds will take into account the transform (rotation) that has been applied, while the frame will not.

To see what I mean, set a breakpoint, and in the debugger print out the description of the top level view `lldb> po [[[[self view] window] rootViewController] view]`

You'll see that the view has a rotation transform and that its frame does not represent the dimensions of the screen in landscape, but represents the dimensions in portrait!

---

The long way to calculate the correct applicationFrame would be

```
BOOL iOS7 = NO;
NSString *currSysVer = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
if ([currSysVer compare:@"7.0" options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
    iOS7 = YES;

CGRect theFrame;
CGRect statusBarFrame = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation])) {

    theFrame.origin = CGPointZero;
    theFrame.size.width = screenBounds.size.height;
    theFrame.size.height = screenBounds.size.width;

    if (iOS7 == NO) {
        // statusBarFrame will be CGRectZero if not visible, so this is safe
        theFrame.size.height -= statusBarFrame.size.width;  // because we're in landscape orientation
    }
}
else {

    theFrame = screenBounds;

    if (iOS7 == NO) {
        // statusBarFrame will be CGRectZero if not visible, so this is safe
        theFrame.size.height -= statusBarFrame.size.height;  // because we're in portrait orientation
    }
}
```

Comment: `[[[[self view] window] rootViewController] view]` is `self.view`. Shouldn't I just be getting the window's bounds? Either way, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Added more detail above. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in current viewcontroller 
// ios 5

```
 -(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
    {


        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation)) {
            return  YES;
        }
        return NO;
    }
```

// ios6

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Comment: This is deprecated in iOS 6. Xcode says I'm supposed to use the 2 methods I'm using instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{


    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape( interfaceOrientation)) 
    {
        return  YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Put this code Appdelegate .M.....